# How to interpolate N points in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, interpolation

The idea is simple, supose i have a collection of 2D points that have N items. I want a path that interpolate that points in a soft way.

I tried using Cubic Bezier but the problem is that it take only 3 point, if i want using N point where N % 3 = 1 or N % 3 = 2 then dosent works, beside even using N % 3 = 0 in the intersection of both Beizers is not soft (make a peak). Using Quadratic Bezier do not work because it is a curve, for example if N = 2, then draws a cuadratic curve betwen both points.

I would like to know a way for do this, if is easy and efficient better.

Comment: Only a comment.  I think you are looking for a spline and that is is not in .NET.  Look on codeproject.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bezier curves can be used to interpolate between any number of points, not just two or three.

Have a look at [constructing Bezier Curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Constructing_B.C3.A9zier_curves) and [the geometric interpretation of De Casteljau's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm#Geometric_interpretation). In particular I've implemented that second link myself in the past, but I'm struggling to put it into better words than the article iteself does.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading right now the articles. Hope works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just for doing this, I implemented a library that can be found in github:

- [Library (Rulyotano.Math)](https://github.com/rulyotano/Rulyotano.Math)
- [Usage Example](https://github.com/rulyotano/wpf-bezier-interpolation)

And all of this is based in this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769055/Interpolate-D-points-usign-Bezier-curves-in-WPF).